# Positioning size labels on lines that delimit the polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, openlayers, labeling, layers

I want to position the label that defines the size of the side of the polygon exactly parallel to the line and not fall on the line above it ...

Here is a picture as it is now:

[image]

Now it is exactly on the line and after the orientation of the line in the middle also in the middle I just want it not to have contact with the line but to be inside or outside the polygon parallel to the line.

Here is the code I have managed to develop so far:

```
var line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 10
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
        placement: 'center',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'black',
            width: 42
        })
    })
});

var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
            name: 'line'
        })]
    }),
});

dist = dist.toFixed(2);
var data = dist + " m";


line_stile.getText().setText(data);
layerLines.setStyle(line_stile);

map.addLayer(layerLines);
```

Comment: You need `placement: 'line'`

Comment: Please do not write solutions in the area reserved for your question.  A solution should be written in the area reserved for answers instead.  It is fine to self-answer your question which a simple cut/paste should enable you to do for this one.

Comment: I'm sorry I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
Thank you Mike I transcribed the solution:

```
 var line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'black'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 10
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: 'bold 19px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
            placement: 'line',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'white',
                width: 42
            })
        })
    });
```